# Concurrency issue when using ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, rest, concurrency, java-8, thread-safety

I've been working on a REST API as part of some up skilling. My current implementation has a small concurrency issue when inserting objects into my ConcurrentHashMap.

My code checks to see whether the consumed JSON contains an ID. If no, I create a new unique ID and insert the object. If yes I continue on to check if the ID already exists in my map. If no object with the ID exists then I insert the object.

The period between checking if the HashMap contains a matching ID and inserting the object is proving to be a problem when many concurrent POST requests are being made. A request that has a generated ID can be potentially written over by a request where the ID has been specified if the first request is executed between `gcdMap.get(obj.getId()) == null` and `gcdMap.put(obj.getId(), obj);` lines of code of the second request. I have been using Thread.Sleep() to reproduce this problem.

```
public static ConcurrentMap<Long, GCDObject> gcdMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, GCDObject>();
@POST

@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public GCDObject create(GCDObject obj) throws GCDRequestException {
    obj.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
    obj.setResult(GCD.calculate(obj.getX(), obj.getY()));

    if (obj.getId() != null) { // JSON contains ID
        if (gcdMap.get(obj.getId()) == null) { // If map does not contain obj with ID already,
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            gcdMap.put(obj.getId(), obj); // Put obj into map.
            return obj;
        } else { // else map already contains ID,
            throw new GCDRequestException();
        }
    } else { // JSON contains no ID
        obj.setId(buildId()); // Build ID
        gcdMap.put(obj.getId(), obj); // Put into map
        return obj;
    }
}
```

I have seen suggestions for the use of locks but have not been able to implement them in a way that solves this issue. Any examples, documentation or articles that might help me work out a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I've misspelled absent about three times in the comments below. I can't edit them now but I noticed!

Comment: Are you using Java 8?

Comment: Yes I am using Java 8.

Comment: have you tried using other ConcurrentHashMap methods like putIfAbsent & getOrDefault and also are the concurrent POST request different or same ?

Comment: I have tried using putIfAbsent. The POST requests being made are 10 null ID JSON objects and one JSON object with the ID of 3. Apart from the JSON the requests are identical.

Comment: Whats your ID generation approach in the buildId() method ? How are you calculating IDs ? like sequential or random ? for Lock you can get an idea from this link http://crunchify.com/what-is-lock-unlock-reentrantlock-trylock-and-how-its-different-from-synchronized-block-in-java/

Comment: If in your buildId() method you are generating normal Integer Id's using primitive data type like int or long & that counter you have made a class level that might be causing issue. Use AtomicInteger or AtomicLong

Comment: ID's are built using AtomicLong with checks to ensure manually inserted ID's are not used. putIfAbscent seems to have done the trick this time around.

Comment: Using `get`, followed by `put` is called the check-then-act anti-pattern. Of course, using locks here would defeat the entire purpose of `ConcurrentHashMap`, specifically designed to provide atomic update methods (like `putIfAbsent`) to avoid locking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`putIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) to insert conditionally:

```
if (gcdMap.putIfAbsent(obj.getId(), obj) == null) { // If map did not contain obj with ID already,
    return obj;
} else { // else map already contained ID,
    throw new GCDRequestException();
}
```

Comment: I gave `putIfAbscent()` another shot and it's doing what I had hoped; I'm thinking I may have forgotten to rebuild my project first time around. Thank you!